# Text Decoration: None !important not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

No matter what I do, I can't remove the underline. I have the right element targeted, as I am able to change every other CSS style, but the underline stays every time. I've looked through about every other question regarding this and no method is working. Not even if I go into chrome dev tools, manually set the element's text-decoration to none.

Screenshot, React component code, and css code below. Link to github: https://github.com/andrewtyl/www.ajessen.com/

[Screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46qwf.jpg)

React Component

```
import React from 'react'
import '../styles//App.css';
import '../styles/normalize.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Header extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <header>
                <Link to="/">
                    <div id="ajessen-logo">
                        <img src={require('../assets/logo-raw.png')} alt="Ajessen Logo" />
                    </div>
                </Link>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <Link to="/">
                            <li>Home</li>
                        </Link>
                        <Link to="/services">
                            <li>Services and Skills</li>
                        </Link>
                        <Link to="/projects">
                            <li>Projects</li>
                        </Link>
                        <Link to="/about">
                            <li>About Me</li>
                        </Link>
                        <Link to="/contact">
                            <li>Contact Me</li>
                        </Link>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
        )
    }
}

export default Header
```

app.css

```
/*
FONTS
Titles: Baloo Tamma 2
Subtitles/Large Text: DM Serif Text
Basic Text: Times New Roman
*/

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo+Tamma+2|DM+Serif+Text&display=swap');

html {
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Baloo Tamma 2', cursive;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'DM Serif Text', cursive;
}

footer {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: auto;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;

}

header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    /*border-bottom: black solid 1px;*/
}

header > nav > ul > a > li {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: black;
}

header > nav {
    width: 60%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: auto;
    display: flex;
}

header > nav > ul {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

header > a {
    width: 40%;
    min-height: 125px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

header > nav > ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-content: flex-end;
    width: 100%
}

#ajessen-logo {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 5%;
    padding-left: 2.5%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: auto;
}

#ajessen-logo > img {
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: auto;
}

#github-footer-icon {
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-left: 25%;
}
```

Comment: Is the underline on the anchor?

Comment: Tried using header > nav > ul > a:hover > li and every a:variation and still doesn't change anything.

Comment: Your 'html is invalid....the only permitted children of a `ul` are `li`....the links should be inside the `li` not the other way round.

Comment: Also text-decoration applies to links...not `li`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two Things , Firstly,You need to change the import of the App.css file from

```
import "./styles//App.css";
```

to

```
import "./styles/App.css";
```

and the CSS property you want to use `text-decoration` not `text-decoration-style` and you want to apply it on the `anchor` no the `list item`

```
 header > nav > ul > a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
 }
```

adding this CSS at the end of the `App.css` file fixes your issue

Comment: Ty. Figured it out seconds before you posted this.

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered an unkillable underline once, took me a while to clue in:

```
a {
  ...
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 2px 2px;
  background-position: 0 100%;
}
```